# Convert a LibGdx image into an acceptable Android Image format

Tags: java, android, libgdx, android-bitmap, scene2d

I need to convert a java LibGdx image of type **com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image** into an image of type "**android.graphics.Bitmap**". I need this because I want to share this image using the Android ACTION_SEND Intent.
Is there any way to convert the LibGdx Image into a Android Bitmap or into java BufferedImage?

Comment: com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Image is an Actor of the scene2dUi, which holds a drawable (the image which you draw on the screen). You have to get this drawable with myImage.getDrawable(). Then you have to know which kind of drawable it is (for example a TextureRegionDrawable) and cast it to that. Then you have to look for methods in the drawable you have. Maybe they have methods, which give you the Bitmap back.

Comment: I tried this, but I didn't find any method in the returned drawable Object that convert it into a bitmap.

Comment: IF you give the Image a TextureRegionDrawable as Drawable you have to cast it to that: ´TextureRegionDrawable trd = (TextureRegionDrawable)image.getDrawable();´. Out of that you can get the TextureRegion: ´trd.getTextureRegion();´. THis Region could help you then.

Comment: does this work for you? I nevr tryed it myself. @Ibrahim Abdulhaq